# django-jquery-file-upload with model OneToOneField

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, file-upload

I am trying to build a small django pictures site using https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload as a blueprint:

My model is the following:

```
class Picture(models.Model):

    test = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="pictures")

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = self.file.name

    super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Picture
    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.test = self.request.user
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        self.object = obj
        files = [serialize(self.object)]
        data = {'files': files}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response
```

I have a ajax button that post pictures just like django-jquery-file-upload, but it will always bug out with ' JSON.parse: unexpected character'

The strange part is if I comment ount:

```
Model
#user = models.OneToOneField(User)
View
#obj.user = self.request.user
```

The website will work.

Could someone shine some light on what is going on?

Jack

Answer (score 0):

I believe the bug is happening in these 2 lines:

```
    files = [serialize(self.object)]

    response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
```

you should test this function in your console: [serialize(self.object)]